# Apple clang: Why can I not create a time_point from std::chrono::nanoseconds

Tags: c++, clang++, c++-chrono

Given this minimal code example in which I construct a time_point from std::chrono::nanoseconds:

```
#include <chrono>

int
main()
{
  std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> t{std::chrono::nanoseconds{10}};
  (void)t;
}
```

As I read things, this should be fine per [specification](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/time_point/time_point/): nanoseconds is a duration and time_point supports construction from a duration. Indeed, this compiles fine using x86_64 clang 11.0.0:

https://godbolt.org/z/jWWzTo

However, on my Mac when I compile this I receive the following error:

```
clang++ -g -Wall -Werror -std=c++17 test.cc -o test
test.cc:6:54: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>'
  std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> t{std::chrono::nanoseconds{10}};
                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/chrono:1355:28: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'std::chrono::nanoseconds' (aka 'duration<long long, ratio<1LL, 1000000000LL> >') to
      'const std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::system_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1, 1000000> > >' for 1st argument
class _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS time_point
                           ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/chrono:1355:28: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'std::chrono::nanoseconds' (aka 'duration<long long, ratio<1LL, 1000000000LL> >') to
      'std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::system_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1, 1000000> > >' for 1st argument
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/chrono:1369:70: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'duration<[...], ratio<[...], 1000000000>>' to 'const duration<[...], ratio<[...], 1000000>>' for 1st argument
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR_AFTER_CXX11 explicit time_point(const duration& __d) : __d_(__d) {}
                                                                     ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/chrono:1374:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'time_point' against 'duration'
    time_point(const time_point<clock, _Duration2>& t,
    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/chrono:1368:61: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR_AFTER_CXX11 time_point() : __d_(duration::zero()) {}
                                                            ^
1 error generated.
```

Here's the clang I'm using:

```
$ clang++ --version
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.26.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Can someone help me understand whether I'm dealing with a compiler bug in the Apple clang compiler or whether I'm getting away with something in the x86_64 clang that isn't strictly supported?

**Update**

Howard's answer points out my problem and provides the solution. Just to make things explicit and maybe avoid confusing others, here's my initial question, quoted from above:

> Can someone help me understand whether I'm dealing with a compiler bug
> in the Apple clang compiler or whether I'm getting away with something
> in the x86_64 clang that isn't strictly supported?

This question has "neither" as the correct answer. I initially wrote my code in libstd c++ on Linux which has nanoseconds as a default duration for time_point. I didn't realize it, but my code implicitly assumed that. And when I tried to build this same code constructing a time_point from a nanosecond duration in Apple clang, it failed to compile because time_point there defaults to microseconds. Thus the compiler warned me of the truncation, which is helpful and certainly not a compiler bug. Once I did as Howard suggested and explicitly instantiated all of my time_points with nanoseconds, I no longer have issues on either system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On macOS, `system_clock::duration` is `microseconds`.  The chrono library is keeping you from accidentally truncating `nanoseconds` to `microseconds` and losing information.  You can either do the truncation manually (say with `duration_cast`), or you can change the type of the `time_point` such that it can store `nanoseconds`:

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::nanoseconds>
    t{std::chrono::nanoseconds{10}};
```

In C++20 the above line can be simplified to:

```
std::chrono::sys_time t{std::chrono::nanoseconds{10}};
```

The type and value of `t` will remain unchanged.  `sys_time` is just a type-alias for a `time_point` based on `system_clock`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two constructors for `time_point` that take a duration.

```
constexpr explicit time_point(const duration& d);
template<class Duration2>
  constexpr time_point(const time_point<clock, Duration2>& t);
```

The first one takes the same duration as the clock provides.
The second one should convert the duration to the one that the clock provides.

As an aside, if I'm reading this right, you're asking for the start of the epoch + 10ns.
If the `system_clock` has a resolution greater than 10ns (and it does), then that should get truncated to zero, and you'll get a `time_point` equal to the start of the epoch.

Now, as to why this doesn't compile.
The second constructor is SFINAE'd based on whether or not the `Duration2` is convertible to `duration` (aka `system_clock::duration`).

And (for libc++, at least), that appears to be false. i.e, this fails:

```
static_assert (std::is_convertible<
                  std::chrono::nanoseconds,
                  std::chrono::system_clock::duration
                  >
                ::value, "");
```

The question then becomes - *should* this be false.

Later: Howard's answer has convinced me that this should be false on Mac OS.

If you're using libstdc++ on Linux, then `std::chrono::system_clock::duration` is, in fact, `std::chrono::nanoseconds`, and so it uses the first constructor.